# Почему объекту не присваивается null?

Tags: javascript

```
const a = {};

    function clear(obj) {
        obj.x = 40;
        obj = null
    }
    clear (a);

    console.log(a)
```

Почему в консоль выводится `{x: 40}`, а не `null`?

Comment: потому что был обнулен один объект (`obj`) а второй (`a`) - нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj` - это локальная переменная функции `clear`. Фактически это ссылка на объект `a` в вашем случае. Поэтому когда вы меняете свойства объекта `obj`, то меняются свойства объекта `a`. Но когда вы меняете саму локальную переменную `obj`, то она просто теряет связь с объектом `a` и начинает указывать уже на что-то другое, но на объект `a` это никак не влияет.

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = {};
function clear(obj) {
    obj.x = 40;
    obj = null;
    console.log(obj)
}
clear (a);
console.log(a);
console.log(a.__proto__= null);


const a = {};
    function clear(obj) {
        obj = null;
        obj.x = 40;
       }
    clear (a);
```

Если имеется ввиду может ли объект в javascript быть null, то по-моему нет. В JavaScript null не является «ссылкой на несуществующий объект» или «нулевым указателем», как в некоторых других языках. Только cвойство **proto** — исторически обусловленный геттер/сеттер для скрытого свойства [[Prototype]] объекта может быть null. Подтверждение моих слов - второй код. А если вопрос проще, то в первой строке фунции  clear obj = a, а во второй строке obj переприсвается значение null, что и показывает console.log(obj) .

Answer (score -1):

потому что obj константа глобальной области видимости,- изменение контанты не вызывает ошибок но переназанчение вызывает. то есть obj это константа, ссылающаяся на изменяемый объект. Сам объект может быть изменён

```
obj.y=555;
delete obj.y;
```

но сама константа изменена быть не может

```
const obj={};
obj=2; #нет ошибок и нет присваивания
var obj=3; #ошибка
```

Comment: Текст тут отвечает на какой-то вопрос, который не был задан